# using array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [url_pic] => Array
        (
            [1001] => lvTbHafU1L2gqnmuSVMrWZzkcGJxORFs.jpg
            [1002] => Da0qf3yKRglNewH6X5n9zShLGubZVQtx.jpg
            [1003] => SGdQJ8h5CjHPkEbYpF9oglatsTfyc0nA.jpg
            [1004] => fikemigfeof330.gif
            [1005] => 7a5083ou41269s.jpg
        )

    [url_post] => Array
        (
            [1001] => http://google.com
            [1002] => http://google.com
            [1003] => http://google.com
            [1004] => http://google.com
            [1005] => http://google.com
        )

    [sort_pic] => Array
        (
            [1001] => 444
            [1002] => 777
            [1003] => 777
            [1004] => 100
            [1005] => 888
        )

)
```

i want to change sort of it like this :

```
Array
(
    [1001] => Array
        (
            [url_pic] => lvTbHafU1L2gqnmuSVMrWZzkcGJxORFsjpg
            [url_post] => http://google.com
            [sort_pic] => 444
        )

    [1002] => Array
        (
            [url_pic] => Da0qf3yKRglNewH6X5n9zShLGubZVQtxjpg
            [url_post] => http://google.com
            [sort_pic] => 777
        )
.......

)
```

it works well with this code :
$set_name = array();

```
foreach ( $result2 as $db_keys => $db_values ) {

//$set_name[] = $db_keys;

                    foreach ( $db_values as $final_key => $final_value ) {
                    $final_value_all[$final_key][$db_keys] = $final_value;
                    //$final_value_all[$final_key][$set_name] = $final_value;
                            }


}
```

**i have no problem with upper code** but i have a question about my commented lines

i write `$db_keys` into `$set_name` so `$set_name` output will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => url_pic
    [1] => url_post
    [2] => sort_pic
)
```

when i want to use`$set_name` in `$final_value_all[$final_key][$set_name] = $final_value;`

i got this error : `Warning: Illegal offset type`

why i can't use`$set_name` in `$final_value_all[$final_key][$set_name] = $final_value;` ?

note : i know it's not necessary to use it , but i want to understanding why i can't using it

Comment: where is your array `$final_value_all`

Comment: bcoz `$set_name` is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `$set_name` is array if you want to use this

do it

```
$final_value_all[$final_key][$set_name[sizeof($set_name)-1]] = $final_value;
```

because

`$set_name[sizeof($set_name)-1]` will be equals to you `$db_keys`

Comment: thankyou a lot , i will be thankful if you explain a little more about your code
i have 2 questions
1- `[$set_name[sizeof($set_name)-1]]` return `[$set_name[2]]` is that true ? because i have 3keys in my `set_names` array , but when i replaced  `[$set_name[2]]` i got error
2- also i wondring why `$db_keys` count is not equal with `$set_names` because i just wrote `$db_keys` into `$set_names`

Comment: because in starting of your outer loop sets `$set_name[0]`

Comment: i replaced `[$set_name[sizeof($set_name)-1]]` with `[$set_name[2]` and i got error
i think i don't understand it ...
i will be thankful if you explain more about this

Comment: Bro $set_name[2] will be set when outer loop will be in 3rd iteration how can be it used in first? `[$set_name[sizeof($set_name)-1]]` will gives you the last one of your `$set_name` array

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an array as an index for another array.

Indexes have to be strings or integers.

If you want to use an array as an index, you can serialize it :

```
array(
    "key1"=>"value1",
    serialize(array('exemple', 'exemple2')) => "value2"
);
```

So you can still get back your array.

Answer (score 0):

in your commented code, $set_name is an array, you can't use it as another array's index.

Comment: but `$db_keys` is some kind of array is that true ?
i just wrote `$db_keys` into `$set_name` so why i can't use it?

Comment: Yes indeed, you did, but as you add `[]` after `$set_name`, you tell him to add it as  value to an array. It's the same as if you wrote `array_push( $set_names, array($bd_keys) );`